# Conceptual question about complex roots of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers, field-theory

I am writing this post to clear up some confusion I have with complex roots of polynomials. I am learning about extensions of fields (e.g. from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$) and have come to realize that I clearly do not understand the concept of roots.

Apparently naively, I thought roots were any values of $x$ in a polynomial $a(x)$ of the form $a(x) = a_0+a_1 x+a_2 x^2 + ... + a_n x^n$ that results in $a(r)=0$. Using graphs as a basic visual understanding of this, I interpreted this as saying *"any value of $x$ that sends $y$ to $0$*, where $y$ is $a(x)$.

Employing https://www.geogebra.org/m/z374cvsr to generate some graphs, I quickly realized that something is wrong with this interpretation.

In line with the idea of field extensions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$, I generated a random quadratic polynomial that has no roots in $\mathbb R$:

> [image: 2D version]

Now, in line with the idea of extension, I took this $2D$ graph to a $3D$ representation where the **imaginary axis** is now in play. However, I also added a plane that intersects through all ordered triplets that have $y=0$ and $x$ and $z$ (the imaginary number value) can be whatever...i.e. $(x,0,z)$.

> [image: 3D Graph]

Firstly, I notice from this picture that the visual interpretation of the polynomial has changed; it is no longer just a line but a surface. In fact, for convenience, at first glance it seems like this polynomial is acting like a function that takes in two values (namely an $x$ value and a $z$ value) and spits out a $y$ value.

In this photo, you will see that I have circled, in yellow, the complex roots of this polynomial. However, I have also traced in a segmented orange line all points of this surface that intersect the plane defined by $(x,y=0,z)$.

Now, using my prior understanding of root, this would seem to imply that this arbitrary quadratic polynomial (which has degree $2$) has an infinite number of roots...because it exhibits an infinite number of points $(x,z)$ that result in a $y$ value of $0$. Obviously, I know that this cannot be true because of a prior theorem my book has outlined...specifically:

> *If $a(x)$ has degree $n$, it has at most $n$ roots.*

(I am aware of the fundamental theorem of algebra, but my book has largely glossed over this). So my question is the following:

*Why are the two yellow-circled points the actual roots of this polynomial but the **other** points on the orange, segmented lines are not?*

Comment: The plot is of the real part of $p(z)$. At a zero of the polynomial, the real and imaginary parts of $p(z)$ vanish simultaneously. You get curves where the real part vanishes, and curves where the imaginary part vanishes. The zeros (roots) of the polynomial are the intersections of these curves.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to convey. What do you mean by "vanishes"?

Comment: "Takes the value $0$", or whatever your preferred way of expressing this is. Since "$f(z) = 0$" is such an important concept, there are lots of ways to say it. One is "$f$ vanishes at $z$". If $f(z) = 0$ for all $z\in S$, one says that "$f$ vanishes on $S$". Here, the real part of $p(z)$ is zero on the curves you indicated with the orange marks. These curves are the two branches of a hyperbola, by the way, since your polynomial is quadratic. But $p(z) = 0$ means that both, the real part and the imaginary part of $p(z)$ have the value $0$ at $z$.

Comment: The imaginary part of $p(z)$ vanishes on a different family of curves (for a quadratic polynomial with real coefficients the real axis and a line perpendicular to it), and the zeros of $p$ are the points where those curves intersect the curves where the real part vanishes.

Comment: @DanielFischer sorry for the continued confusion. So when you say "the imaginary part of $p(z)$ vanishes", you're saying $p(I(a_1+ib_1))=0$? ...i.e. all values of $b$ that result in $0$?

Comment: Not $p(I(a_1 + ib_1)) = 0$ but $I(p(a + ib)) = 0$. Let's take the very simple $p(z) = z^2 + 1$. If we split it into real and imaginary part, writing $z = a + ib$, we get $$p(a+ib) = (a+ib)^2 + 1 = (a^2 - b^2 + 2iab) + 1 = (a^2 - b^2 + 1) + i(2ab)\,.$$ The real part of that is $a^2 - b^2 + 1$. This vanishes on the hyperbola $b^2 - a^2 = 1$. The imaginary part is $2ab$, which is zero if $a = 0$ or $b = 0$. So for $p(a+ib) = 0$ we need 1. $b^2 - a^2 = 1$, and 2. $a = 0$ or $b = 0$. Now for $b = 0$ we have $b^2 - a^2 = -a^2 \leqslant 0 < 1$, so that line doesn't intersect the hyperbola, $p$ has

Comment: no roots on the real axis. For $a = 0$ we have $b^2 - a^2 = b^2$, and that equals $1$ if $b = \pm 1$. So the real and imaginary part of $p(z)$ both are zero precisely at the points $a + ib$ with $a = 0$ and $b = \pm 1$, that is, for $0 + i1 = i$ and for $0 + i(-1) = -i$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you for the clarification. However, I am still quite confused about the complex values that also yield a $y$ value of $0$ (i.e. the orange segmented lines). The blue surface that is illustrated in the second picture IS the polynomial $p(z)$ depicted as the ordered triplet $(x_{axis}=a, y_{axis}=p(z), imaginary_{\ axis}=b)$, right?

Comment: No, the blue surface is the graph of the real part of $p$, the vertical axis corresponds to $\operatorname{Re} p(z)$. The graph of the polynomial is a two-dimensional surface in the four-dimensional space $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$. That is difficult to depict, however.

Comment: @DanielFischer ohhhhh. So the polynomial $p(z)$ is actually a function from $\mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ (not from $\mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb R$ as I mistakenly understood it to be)